# Assigning a public ip to an ec2 in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

In the vpc I am using on aws ec2's do not get a public ip address by default. I am trying to add one manually after referencing [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-networkinterfaces) and [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html#aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded-deviceindex) bit of documentation.

Currently my cloudformation template includes

```
"netinterface"    : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
  "Properties" : {
    "SubnetId" : {"Ref": "Subnet"}
   }


},


"billingattributionapi" : {
  "Type"        : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties"  : {

    "NetworkInterfaces" : [
      {
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress"  : "true",
        "DeviceIndex"               : "eth0",
        "NetworkInterfaceId"        : {"Ref" : "netinterface"},
        "DeleteOnTermination"       : "true"
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

There is a lot omitted, but this is everything relevant to adding an ip.

My problem is that the documentation says that only network interfaces with a DeviceIndex of eth0 can have a public ip address, but using eth0 results in an error saying

```
    Encountered non numeric value for property DeviceIndex
```

But if I set the device id to 0 I will get

```
The associatePublicIPAddress parameter cannot be specified for a network interface with an ID
```

But if I remove the NetworkInterfaceId and add a subnet id as required by the documentation I get

```
Network interfaces and an instance-level subnet ID may not be specified on the same request
```

At this point I have no idea what I should do. According to the documentation my original approach seems correct. Has anyone done this before and can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This is what works for me:

Set a private IP as primary IP address in "AWS::EC2::Instance" resource:

```
  "NetworkInterfaces" : [
                {
                    "DeleteOnTermination" : true,
                    "Description"         : "Main interface",
                    "DeviceIndex"         : "0",
                    "PrivateIpAddresses"  : [
                        {
                            "PrivateIpAddress" : {
                                "Ref" : "InternalIPAddress"
                            },
                            "Primary"          : true
                        }
                    ],
                    "GroupSet"            : [
                        {
                            "Ref" : "SecurityGroupId"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SubnetId"            : {
                        "Ref" : "VPCSubnet"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Note that the reference to "InternalIPAddress" above is a parameter to pass what internal IP the machine should have.  I don't think it's necessary, as without it, the instance will pick up an IP through dhcp.

Then later in the template, add a resource of type "AWS::EC2::EIP":

```
 "EIPExternalIP"                 : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::EIP",
        "Properties" : {
            "InstanceId" : {
                "Ref" : "Instance"
            },
            "Domain"     : "vpc"
        }
    },
```

You can get the External IP with {"Ref" : "EIPExternalIP"}